# How to upgrade core data when app of new version has a new bundle ID very unlike the old version?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a problem when upgrading our app. The old one and the new version have two different bundle IDs and these two have very unlike core data. So when I make a test to upgrade the old version to the new one, the new version can't read any data from old one. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Isn't it new version of App have the exact same Bundle ID as old one?

Comment: This question is very unclear; what exactly about the new app is failing to work? This isn't just an "app" question, it's a program-specific backwards compatibility question.

Comment: You have to add a newer version of object model  manually as your app id is different in the newer version of the app .  Check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html

Comment: Two different bundle ids means it is a completely new app that can coexist with the old app. There's no need to deal with upgrading in such a case.

Comment: this app, we have two different bundle ID, but the app name is the same. And just now, I reset the simulator and upgraded my app, the new version could read data from the old one.